# Can't rate apps/music/etc in iTunes or App Store

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore, ios-appstore

I'm unable to rate anything in either iTunes, the Mac app store, or the iOS app store.  If I rate an app 5 stars (or anything else), and then return to the search results, then go back to the app page the rating widget will appear as if I hadn't rated the app.  The rating count does not increase either.  It's has been happening for a while.  I only just noticed the behavior a week or two ago when I got my iPad, but it may have been an issue before that on my Mac.

I'm assuming something may be wrong with my Apple ID, but I dont know what it could be.

Comment: When you open iTunes on a PC and view your account - do you see counts for the number of ratings and reviews?

Answer (score 1):

Apple blocked your account. You can still download apps but cannot post reviews or rate them